# Router drops connection often when webserver is running

Tags: networking, router, webserver

I have a network setup that goes

Modem -> Wireless Router -> Network Switch -> 1U Rackmount server, other desktops

I am forwarding port 80 to the server for incoming web requests. Recently I have been having alot of issues with the router dropping the network connection briefly, wireless and wired both. Its as if the router keeps rebooting. This only seems to be an issue with the server running.

I know this question is too broad to answer with very specific causes but I was just wondering if there are general issues with mid-range routers forwarding connections to a server. Should i not be using a general mid-range wireless router for forwarding? Would a heavy duty wired router with a wireless access point on the switch work better generally?

Im using the Asus RT-N16, spent about $100 on it a couple of years ago.

Comment: Without knowing how much web server traffic you're getting, it's hard to know if your router is sufficient for the task.

Comment: Its pretty low traffic, analytics is showing maybe 30 sessions per day.

Answer (score 1):

## Wired is better

There's generally less overhead, latency, and signal interference when using wired instead of wireless.

## Power is Important

If your router is rebooting, you might want to make sure it's getting sufficient, reliable power.  The increased load due to the web server could be causing it to draw more power than its adapter can reliably provide.

If you don't trust the power coming out of your wall, you could get an Uninterruptible Power Supply (UPS) / Battery Backup and plug your router into that.

## Internet Service Provider (ISP)

Your ISP may not provide a reliable Internet connection, especially if you are saturating the upload bandwidth with a web server.  My Internet tanks when I'm uploading big files to the cloud.

Comment: Thank you, was really just looking for some general tips. I will take a look at these.